# Создать объект класса в одной кнопку и использовать в другой

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

При выборе radioButton1, создается объект класса Angle1, с ним нужно работать при выборе других радоибаттон, но они его не видят.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {


    //add
    if (radioButton1->Checked) {
        Angle1 an;
        an.deg =Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);
        an.min = Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text);
        an.todm();          
    }
    //plus
    if (radioButton2->Checked) {
        an.plus(Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text), Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text));
        an.todm();
    }
    //minus
    if (radioButton3->Checked) {
        an.minus(Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text), Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text));
        an.todm();
    }
    //sinus
    if (radioButton4->Checked) {
        textBox3->Text = Convert::ToString(an.sinus());
    }

    textBox4->Text = Convert::ToString(an.dm);
    textBox5->Text = Convert::ToString(an.rad);
    textBox6->Text = Convert::ToString(an.deg);
    textBox7->Text = Convert::ToString(an.min);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите Angle an; за пределы if-оператора

Comment: Тогда при каждом нажатии кнопки будет создаваться новый Angle an, а нужно работать с тем что создается в radioButton1

Comment: У вас итак он создается при каждом нажатии кнопки, но только в случае если выделена radio1. Создайте его как поле класса тогда и используйте этот экземпляр. И почитайте про область видимости переменных.